# Envers/Audit creation-date/time in HQL

Tags: java, hql, hibernate-envers

I have this NNT:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Sender</th>
        <th>Arrived</th>
    </tr>
    {{for ms = SELECT em.subject.subject as sd, em.id as emid FROM EMail em LEFT JOIN em.inFolders f WHERE f.owner.id=:accountid AND f.id=:mf}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{sd}}</td>
            <td>
                {{for s = SELECT a.localName.localName as l, a.domain.domainName as d FROM EMailAddress a LEFT JOIN a.sent s WHERE s.id=:emid}}
                    <tt>{{l}}@{{d}}</tt>
                {{/for}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/for}}
</table>
```

How can I get the creation-date/time of the INSERT-Statement of the EMail (em) in HQL?

I expected something like this:

```
 SELECT CREATED(em) FROM EMail em LEFT JOIN em.inFolders f WHERE ...
```

But it throws me:

```
WARN: [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 135 in HQL: [ SELECT em.subject.subject as sd, em.id as emid, created(em) as cd FROM EMail em LEFT JOIN em.inFolders f WHERE f.owner.id=? AND f.id=?].  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
NO JPQL FROM  SELECT em.subject.subject as sd, em.id as emid, created(em) as cd FROM EMail em LEFT JOIN em.inFolders f WHERE f.owner.id=? AND f.id=? BECAUSE No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'created' {originalText=created}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'email0_.id' {alias=em, className=EMail, tableAlias=email0_}
 [ SELECT em.subject.subject as sd, em.id as emid, created(em) as cd FROM EMail em LEFT JOIN em.inFolders f WHERE f.owner.id=? AND f.id=?]
```

Comment: Is the date you're trying to fetch one which you've annotated on your base entity using `@CreationTimestamp` or are you attempting to get the date from the revision entity itself which is stored in the table called `REVINFO`.

Comment: Naros, the second one :), a column containing the creation-timestamp AND the same timestamp in the revinfo would mean a redundancy.

Comment: Must this be HQL or can you actually delegate this to some java code to execute and return you a timestamp?  It would be much simplier for you if the latter is possible rather than just HQL.

Comment: @Naros NNT means NN-Template and create plain jdbc out of HQL and compiles the java-source-code to java-byte-code at runtime. It must be HQL because I decide at runtime what Entitys to use. At the end it must be jdbc so yes, I guess it must be HQL.